# MultiChoiceModeListener onItemCheckedStateChanged weird behavior

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have gridview and MultiChoiceModeListener attached to it.
I have set

```
gridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
gridView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(multiChoiceModeListener);
```

The problem is that onItemCheckedStateChanged() callback of MultiChoiceModeListener is getting called erroneously. Sometimes it is getting called for views that i have not selected and sometimes it is getting called for the same view twice.

As of now am just logging the status inside onItemCheckedStateChanged

```
 @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int position, long l, boolean isSelected) {
            Log.d(TAG,"CALLED "+position);
}
```

Any pointers on why this is happening?

Comment: Hmmm....something else is happening.  What adapter are you using? If custom, can you please post the code?

Comment: @JaySoyer Figured it out. I was using https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout for grid view layout and adapter. Removing it solved the issue. But still i have to find out what exactly was happening.